# Possible to expose the duration in which a question or answer has been edited/viewed, and in draft form?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

I think it would be interesting to have a statistical analysis of upvotes/duration of view/total viewers of editing or viewing a SE question.

For example, I may want to prioritize reading something that has 100 views, with 50 total hours spent, versus something with 100 views with 10 minutes spent.

This could be used to sway the "Interesting questions" tag.

I didn't see this in the SE API, but if this metric is stored internally, I would like to access it on a public basis.

Comment: I believe this data is in the [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) data, in the PostHistory table. For the editing part, not the viewing part.

Comment: We wouldn't ever store this kind of information because it's mostly useless information. I mean, I leave random questions up on my screen *all the time* even though I'm not actually looking at or doing anything with them, and a lot of moderation-focused users especially do the same. "Amount of time spent" never actually reflects the amount of time spent when it's something online. It's just random numbers. For example, I actually typed this comment 20 minutes ago when you posted this question, but got distracted and just left it typed in a box without looking at it.

Comment: @animuson you mean like MY comment, basically saying the exact same thing, that I left in the comment box when I first saw this question, then refreshed before posting, and saw yours? :P

Comment: Oh I thought browsers exposed some kind of 'is focused' or `can capture mouse` property

Comment: Even with an ability to detect things like that, it's still possible to leave a window open in a focused state while not looking at it. As well, any sort of tracking would have to be done client-side, which means it could very easily be tampered with or altered by the user to make the stats inaccurate.